# Python: Defining a minimum bounding rectangle

Tags: python, list, numpy, 2d, gis

I have data in the following format, a list of 2d x,y coordinates:

```
[(6, 7), (2, 4), (8, 9), (3, 7), (5, 4), (9, 9)]
```

and I'm trying to iterate through the list to find the minimum bounding box in the format [(minx,miny),(maxx,miny),(maxx,maxy),(minx,maxy)]

Thus I've written the below code, however it doesn't appear to be working. Potentially to do with the fact that I'm not passing it an array rather a list. the input and code is below, print coords returns the list previously mentioned:

```
os.chdir("filepath")
with open ('file.csv') as csvfile:
    coords = [(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ',')]
print coords


def bounding_box(coords):
    min_x, min_y = numpy.min(coords[0], axis=0)
    max_x, max_y = numpy.max(coords[0], axis=0)
    return numpy.array(
        [(min_x, min_y), (max_x, min_y), (max_x, max_y), (min_x, max_y)])
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? feel free to disregard the entire code above if its not helping.

Comment: You could try searching on Google as "minimum bounding rectangle" or you could read about "Hull algorithm". Also you could give an input/output sample.

Comment: @christian thanks, I've tried googling but I can't find anything for the mbr in terms of constructing from my data input. Also the convex hull algorithm is too complex for what i need, simply defining four corners will suffice.

Comment: Please as I told you, can you give an input/output sample? So is easier for us to help you.

Comment: All you need to do to make it work is drop the `[0]` from the calls to `np.min` and `np.max`, i.e. `np.min(coords, axis=0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just iterate through the list with four counters: `min_x`, `min_y`, `max_x`, and `max_y`

```
def bounding_box(coords):

  min_x = 100000 # start with something much higher than expected min
  min_y = 100000
  max_x = -100000 # start with something much lower than expected max
  max_y = -100000

  for item in coords:
    if item[0] < min_x:
      min_x = item[0]

    if item[0] > max_x:
      max_x = item[0]

    if item[1] < min_y:
      min_y = item[1]

    if item[1] > max_y:
      max_y = item[1]

  return [(min_x,min_y),(max_x,min_y),(max_x,max_y),(min_x,max_y)]
```

Using your example input:

```
bounding_box([(6, 7), (2, 4), (8, 9), (3, 7), (5, 4), (9, 9)])
>> [(2, 4), (9, 4), (9, 9), (2, 9)]
```

Comment: @matt_stokes , that is all working now, thanks! It might not be the perfect solution because of defining the min and max values but it does the job.

Comment: The min and max values will always be overwritten provided you have at least 1 element in your list. To be 100% safe you should add a condition for an empty list

Comment: For starting out with maximum and minimum values, would recommend using `math.inf` and `-math.inf` respectively

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that you are searching for a vector min/max and instead you should be searching by each of the verctor dimensions (two in your case). 
so you should look for the min for X and the min for Y and the same for the max.

The correct approach would be:

```
min_x, min_y = numpy.min(coords[...,0]), numpy.min(coords[...,1])
max_x, max_y = numpy.max(coords[...,0]), numpy.max(coords[...,1])
return numpy.array(
    [(min_x, min_y), (max_x, min_y), (max_x, max_y), (min_x, max_y)])
```

`coords[...,0]` and `coords[...,1]`  means that you are selecting values from a specific dimension (X or Y respectively).

In order for all of this to work properly you should also make the list of coordinates to be a numpy twodimensional array instead of list of tuples.

Comment: Your two calls to `np.min` are equivalent, for a 2D array, to `np.min(coords, axis=0)`, and the  same applies to the two calls to `np.max`.

Comment: Thanks, i did not know that, i'm relatively new to numpy, in general the code example i gave works just fine. The issue that ```user3115802``` had was only the [0] part as you noted in your comment